# Symfony 2 StofDoctrineExtensionBundle timestampable with odm (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried using the timestampable behavior from `StofDoctrineExtenstion` for my object, but it doesn't work. Object is saved successfully, but `createdAt` property isn't saved.

This my config:

```
#Doctrine ODM Configuration
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options:
                connect: true
    default_database: rent
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true

#stof doctrine extension
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    mongodb:
        default:
            timestampable: true
```

and class (I also tried using timestampable behavior for my main object)

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @MongoDB\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseApartment
{

     /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    private $createdAt;
}
```

Symfony 2.0.12, my `deps` file:

```
[StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle]
    git=git://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
    version=v1.0 (also tried version 1.1)

[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
    git=git://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
    target=gedmo-doctrine-extensions
```

What's wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: What ever happened to this? I'm having the same issue atm.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a matter of version compatibility. The problem (well maybe not *the* problem, but at least *one* problem) seems to be that the "master" branches of **gedmo-doctrine-extensions** Stof's **DoctrineExtensionsBundle** are not compatible with each other.

For example I just made mine work with this pairing of versions (for Symfony version 2.0.15):

```
[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
    git=git://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
    version=origin/doctrine2.1.x

[DoctrineExtensionsBundle]
    git=git://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
    version=origin/1.0.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the version in your `deps` file to:

```
[Stof-DoctrineExtensionsBundle]
   git=https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
   target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
   version=origin/1.0.x
```

I was having the same issue until I made that change, followed by a `bin/vendors install --reinstall`, and it started working for me.